# Add radio button to razor page by loading from model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I want to load radio button for tracker from CustomerIssue model and display in razor page and select one tracker by updating Checked property. Hope I get some help from the community.

```
public class Tracker
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerIssue
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public List<Tracker> Trackers = new List<Tracker>
        {
            new Tracker {Name ="Bug" },
            new Tracker {Name ="Addition"},
            new Tracker {Name= ="Develop"},
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all?
[Radio buttons](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/radios)

If not do you have any more information on what you are trying to acheive and/or a sample of your razor file?